# Recuperar arquivos excluídos com git

Tags: git, github

Criei um repositório no github , deu o git init da minha pasta e após isso eu fiz a besteira de dar esses dois comandos abaixo, após isso meus arquivos que estavam na minha pasta sumiram... como voltar os arquivos ? eu ainda não tinha dado nenhum commit.

```
git add -A

git reset --hard


deivison@Desso MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/adega (master)
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .editorconfig
        new file:   .gitignore
        new file:   .htaccess
        new file:   application/.htaccess
        new file:   application/cache/index.html
        new file:   application/config/autoload.php
        new file:   application/config/config.php
        new file:   application/config/constants.php
        new file:   application/config/database.php
        new file:   application/config/doctypes.php
        new file:   application/config/foreign_chars.php
        new file:   application/config/hooks.php
        new file:   application/config/index.html
        new file:   application/config/memcached.php
        new file:   application/config/migration.php
        new file:   application/config/mimes.php
        new file:   application/config/profiler.php
        new file:   application/config/routes.php
        new file:   application/config/smileys.php
        new file:   application/config/user_agents.php
        new file:   application/controllers/Cliente.php
        new file:   application/controllers/Entrada.php
        new file:   application/controllers/Movimentacao.php
        new file:   application/controllers/Produto.php
        new file:   application/controllers/Saida.php
        new file:   application/controllers/Template.php
        new file:   application/controllers/Venda.php
        new file:   application/controllers/index.html
        new file:   application/core/index.html
        new file:   application/helpers/index.html
        new file:   application/hooks/index.html
        new file:   application/index.html
        new file:   application/language/english/index.html
        new file:   application/language/index.html
        new file:   application/libraries/index.html
        new file:   application/logs/index.html
        new file:   application/models/M_Cliente.php
        new file:   application/models/M_Produto.php
        new file:   application/models/index.html
        new file:   application/third_party/index.html
        new file:   application/views/entrada.php




deivison@Desso MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/adega (master)
$ git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

deivison@Desso MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/adega (master)
$ git reset --hard
```

Comment: Recomendo que leia esse [guia básico](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html)(está em português), vai familiarizar você com os comandos e funcionamento básico do `git`.

Comment: Vê se consegue restaurar com `git checkout .`. Eu faço isso sempre que modifico alguma coisa.

Comment: deivison@Desso MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/adega (estoque)
$ git checkout .
error: pathspec '.' did not match any file(s) known to git.

deivison@Desso MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/adega (estoque)
$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Está dando esso erro, e eu não consigo voltar para a branch master

Answer (score 1):

Tente rever no log o que aconteceu com o comando `git log` ou se preferir utilize o comando `git log -p -2`. Isso fará exibir o histórico com *diff* das duas últimas alterações ou se preferir utilize esse comando para dar um resumo do log:

```
git log --pretty=oneline
```

(lembrando que esse comando vai exibir informações resumidas em uma linha *hash* completa e comentário);

Após feito isso e verificado tente recuperar com os comandos: git checkout -- nomedoarquivo ou se não tente git reset `HEAD` nomedoarquivo.

Comment: $ git log
fatal: your current branch 'estoque' does not have any commits yet 
Ele dá esse erro porque não dei nenhum commit nessa branch.. e não consigo voltar para a branch master

Comment: @user120419 já tentou `git checkout HEAD nomedoarquivo`? @JoaoRobertoAnjos , evite postar duas ou mais respostas. Qualquer coisa basta clicar em *editar* e corrigir/complementá-la.